# Оптимизация кода

Tags: строки, c++

```
int main ()
{
    char psz[256];
    cout<<"Vvedite predlozheniya\n";
    fgets(psz, sizeof(psz), stdin);

    int nwords;
    cout<<"Vvedite kol-vo slov\n";
    cin>>nwords;

    printf("string = %s\n\n",psz);

    for (int i = 0; psz[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        char pchars[] = "!?."; 
        int k = i, cnt = 0;

        while (!strchr(pchars,psz[i]) && psz[i] != '\0')
            if (psz[i++] == ' ') cnt++;

        int n = k; 
        if (k == 0) cnt++;
        char temp[256] = "\0"; 
        int s = 0;
        while (n <= i && cnt == nwords) 
            temp[s++] = psz[n++];

        if (cnt == nwords) 
            printf("%s\n",temp);
    }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Приветствую. Возможно ли как-то упростить или может даже реализовать иным способом? Здесь вводятся предложения и число, дальше на экран выведутся только те предложения в которых кол-во слов равно введенному числу.

Comment: Замечание №1: не смешивайте в одном коде С- и С++-стили.

Comment: @RubyNut, несколько вопросов, ответив себе на которые, Вы сами поправите программу:

1)  а что будет если слова разделены не одним, а несколькими пробелами?

2)  является ли отделенная пробелами от 2-х запятая  словом? А числа в тексте?

3)   предложение, скопированное в tmp[] завершается нулем?

4) а зачем его вообще копировать, если известны индексы его начала и конца, а также существует функция putchar() (или cout << в C++)?

5) `\n` прочитанный fgtes() в конец psz[] что это такое?

Comment: @avp, благодарствую,очень полезный список замечаний, сейчас попробую исправить

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вариант номер 1 (с strtok_r()). Предложен @LoOnly. Компактная и логичная (на мой взгляд) программа. Линукс, компилировал g++ и gcc.

В дальнейшем планирую показать еще два варианта и сравнить их быстродействие.

```
// tstrtok.c печать предложений с заданным (av[1]) количеством слов (av[1]==0 все)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define delims " \t\n.<,>?/~`!@$%^&*()-+=[]{}\\|;:'\""
#define sdelims ".?!;"

char *
trim (char *str)
{
  char *s = str;

  while (*s && strchr(delims,*s))
    s++;
  s = strdup(s);
  char *t = s+strlen(s)-1;
  while (t > s && strchr(delims,*t))
    t--;
  *++t = 0;
  return s;
}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char text[1024], *sentence, *snt_copy, *psntc;
  int  desiredWordsNumber = av[1]? atoi(av[1]):0, wordcnt;

  while (puts("Enter text"),fgets(text,1024,stdin)) {
    sentence = strtok_r(text,sdelims,&psntc);
    if (sentence)
      do {
        wordcnt = 0;
        snt_copy = strdup(sentence);
        char  *pword, *word = strtok_r(snt_copy,delims,&pword);
        if (word)
          do {
            wordcnt++;
          } while(word = strtok_r(NULL,delims,&pword));
        free(snt_copy);
        if (wordcnt && (!desiredWordsNumber || wordcnt == desiredWordsNumber)) {
          printf ("[%s]\n",snt_copy = trim(sentence));
          free(snt_copy);
        }
      } while (sentence = strtok_r(NULL,sdelims,&psntc));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Компилируем и запускаем (сначала печать всех предложений, потом только из 2-х слов)

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ -O3 tstrtok.c -o tstrtok
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./tstrtok 
Enter text
мама мыла раму, кот жрал мясо. папа ржал
[мама мыла раму, кот жрал мясо]
[папа ржал]
Enter text
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./tstrtok 2
Enter text
test, test, test; test,   test??? yes test !!!! simple short test.
[test,   test]
[yes test]
Enter text
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Думаю, в принципе все ясно. Продолжение (вместе с замерами времени) следует...

***Обещанное продолжение***

Сделал еще один вариант (nword.c), от которого ожидал большего быстродействия, но он оказался раза в 4 медленнее, чем приведенная выше программа с strtok_r().

Идея, поначалу казавшаяся весьма здравой, заключалась в поиске начала и конца слов (по разделителям) и анализе разделителей, завершающих слово на наличие символа конца предложения. При этом запоминался индекс первого слова предложения, а при нахождении символа конца предложения все оно печаталось без промежуточного копирования.

Собственно основной цикл программы, реализующей этот алгоритм тоже невелик. Вот он, с дополнениями вывода в /dev/null при измерении времени исполнения в цикле

```
  // собственно цикл подсчета слов в каждом предложениии и печать
  wordcnt = curpos = 0;
  while (getWordBeg(str,curpos,&start)) {
    if (!wordcnt)
      sentenceBegin = start;
    curpos = getWordEnd(str,start);
    wordcnt++;
    if (isSentence(str,&curpos)) {  
      if (desiredWordsNumber < 1 || wordcnt == desiredWordsNumber) {
        int i = sentenceBegin, end = ctrim(str,i,curpos);
        fputc('[',out);
        while (i < end && str[i] && str[i] != '\n')
          fputc(str[i++],out); 
        fputs("]\n",out);
      }
      wordcnt = 0;
    }
  }
```

16 строк, а в программе с strtok_r() 15 строк. Функции `getWordBeg`, `getWordEnd`, `isSentence` и `ctrim` очевидны и используют стандартные `strchr`, `strspn` и `strcspn` для поиска разделителей.

Сравнение скорости работы показало *совершенно неожиданный для меня результат*.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./tstrtok 
Enter text
и пишу я тесты. разные тесты. тесты, тесты, тесты... что толку от них?
[и пишу я тесты]
[разные тесты]
[тесты, тесты, тесты]
[что толку от них]
Enter text
1000000 и пишу я тесты. разные тесты. тесты, тесты, тесты... что толку от них?
1000000 loops 497 msec
Enter text
1000000 и пишу я тесты. разные тесты. тесты, тесты, тесты... что толку от них?
1000000 loops 592 msec
Enter text
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc -O3  nwords.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
Enter text
1000000 и пишу я тесты. разные тесты. тесты, тесты, тесты... что толку от них?
1000000 loops 2238 msec
Enter text
1000000 и пишу я тесты. разные тесты. тесты, тесты, тесты... что толку от них?
1000000 loops 2243 msec
```

Программа вызывающая strtok и по логике вещей, копирующая весь текст во внутренний буфер, оказалась **быстрее в 4 раза!**.

Попытка оптимизировать nword, заменив стандартные `strchr`, `strspn` и `strcspn` вариантами с поиском разделителей в хэш-таблицах оказалась совсем некудышней.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc -O3 -DUSE_HASH  nwords.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out
Enter text
1000000 и пишу я тесты. разные тесты. тесты, тесты, тесты... что толку от них?
1000000 loops 4369 msec
```

Оказалось, что реализация defina-ми `strchr`, `strspn` и `strcspn` в /usr/include/bits/string2.h весьма нетривиальна и видимо действительно эффективна, а с хэшированием возможно надо разобраться поплотнее.

Великолепный же результат strtok_r, как выяснилось благодаря **gdb**, омрачается тем, что она **модифицирует исходную строку**, записывая нули на место разделителей. Т.е. никакого копирования не происходит, но это описано в конце manpage (интересно, я один такой невнимательный, что сначала берусь за дебаггер, а потом уже внимательно читаю man ???)

Вот это слова их man 3 strtok

```
BUGS
       Be cautious when using these functions.  If you do use them, note that:

       * These functions modify their first argument.

       * These functions cannot be used on constant strings.

       * The identity of the delimiting character is lost.
```

Надеюсь кому-нибудь это небольшое исследование пригодится.

***продолжение***

[[@RubyNub](/users/6638/rubynub)](/users/6638/rubynub), еще о `trim()`

Дело в том, что `strtok_r()` в цикле по предложениям может оставить после последнего слова в предложении разделители слов, которые не являются разделителями предложений. Вообще trim сделан для "похожести" на ответ [[[[@gkuznets](/users/5638/gkuznets)](/users/5638/gkuznets)](/users/5638/gkuznets)](/users/5638/gkuznets).

Итак, выяснив природу ошибки, возникающей при замере времени в программе с `strtok_r` (напомню, эта функция пишет нули в разбираемый текст и не восстанавливает его) пришлось запоминать весь введенный текст и восстанавливать его перед каждым циклом.  Программа приобрела следующий вид, а время ее работы увеличилось до 1700-1800 миллисекунд (миллион циклов).

```
// печать предложений с заданным (av[1]) количеством слов (av[1]==NULL все)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define delims " \t\n.<,>?/~`!@$%^&*()-+=[]{}\\|;:'\""
#define sdelims ".?!;"

// копия предложения с обрезанием разделителей в начале и конце
char *
trim (char *str)
{
  char *s = str, *t;

  while (*s && strchr(delims,*s))  // найдем начало текста (не разделитель)
    s++;
  /*
    копируем
    strlen, malloc, memcpy сделано вместо strdup, strlen
    чтобы убрать лишний проход по s (два в strdup + еще один в strlen)
  */
  int  l =  strlen(s)+1;
  t = (char *)malloc(l);
  memcpy(t,s,l);
  s = t;
  t += (l-1); // позиция перед завершающим 0

  while (t > s && strchr(delims,*t)) // пробегаем разделители в конце
    t--;
  *++t = 0;   // "удаляем" их
  return s;
}

long long mutime(void);

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char text[1024], copy[sizeof(text)], *sentence, *snt_copy, *psntc;
  int  desiredWordsNumber = av[1]? atoi(av[1]):0, wordcnt;

  // для замера времени
  FILE *out = stdout, *nullout = fopen("/dev/null","w");
  int  nloops, i;
  volatile int l = 1;
  long long tstart, dt, ct;

  while (puts("Enter text"),fgets(text,1024,stdin)) {

    // для замера времени
    if ((nloops = atoi(text)) < 1)
      nloops = 1;
    if (nloops > 1) {
      out = nullout;
      tstart = mutime();
      l = strlen(text);
      for (i = 0; i < nloops; i++)
        memcpy(copy,text,l);
      ct = mutime()-tstart;
      printf ("copytime %d bytes %d loops %lld %s\n", l, nloops,
          ct < 10000? :ct/1000, ct < 10000? "usec" : "msec");
      tstart = mutime();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nloops; i++, memcpy(text,copy,l)) {

      // собственно цикл подсчета слов в каждом предложениии и печать
      sentence = strtok_r(text,sdelims,&psntc);
      if (sentence)
        do {
          wordcnt = 0;
          snt_copy = strdup(sentence);
          char  *pword, *word = strtok_r(snt_copy,delims,&pword);
          if (word)
            do {
              wordcnt++;
            } while(word = strtok_r(NULL,delims,&pword));
          free(snt_copy);
          if (wordcnt && (!desiredWordsNumber || wordcnt == desiredWordsNumber)) {
            fprintf (out,"[%s]\n",
                 snt_copy = trim(sentence));

            free(snt_copy);

          }
        } while (sentence = strtok_r(NULL,sdelims,&psntc));

    } // end for nloops, print time
    if (out == nullout) {
      out = stdout;
      dt = mutime()-tstart - ct;
      printf ("%d loops %lld %s\n", nloops,
          dt < 10000? :dt/1000, dt < 10000? "usec" : "msec");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

#include <sys/time.h>

long long
mutime()
{
  struct timeval t;

  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000000 + t.tv_usec;
  return mt;
}
```

Вспомнив, что вопрос автора был об оптимизации (по времени исполнения?) задачи сделал еще одну версию. Исходные данные и вид результата те же, что и в `nwords` и `tstrtok`, а алгоритм немного другой, основан на поиске индексов (позиций в тексте) начала и конца слова, плюс оптимизировано определение является ли очередной символ разделителем. Для этого используем массивы по 256 символов и значение проверяемого символа как индекс в таком массиве.

Вот текст наиболее быстрого варианта.

```
// ncwords.c считает количество слов в предложении

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// все разделители
#define delims " \t\n.<,>?/~`!@$%^&*()-+=[]{}\\|;:'\""
// разделители предложений (подмножество delims)
#define sdelims ".?!;"

/**
 * makeset сделать множество однобайтных символов
 * @set:   [out]  результат: массив, индексируемый символами
 * @str:   [in]   строка, символы которой помещаем в set
 */
static void
makeset (char set[256], const char *str)
{
  memset(set,0,256);
  while (*str) 
    set[*(u_char *)str] = *str++;
}

/**
 * isSentence         ищет в text символ конца предложения среди разделителей
 * text               [in]   текст со словами
 * wordDelimiters     [in]   множество разделителей слов
 * sentenceDelimiters [in]   множество разделителей предложений
 *                           (должно быть подмножеством wordDelimiters)
 * endWord            [in]   позиция первого разделителя после слова в text 
 * pos                [out]  указатель на int, куда заносится позиция
 *                           первого символа из sentenceDelimiters среди
 *                           последовательности символов из wordDelimiters 
 *                           или первого символа, не входящего в wordDelimiters
 *
 *   возвращает 1, если конец предложения найден  и 0 если не найден
 */
static int
isSentence (char *text, char wordDelimiters[256], 
        char sentenceDelimiters[256], int endWord, int *pos)
{

  do {
    if (sentenceDelimiters[(u_char)text[endWord]] || !text[endWord]) {
      *pos = endWord;
      return 1;
    }
    endWord++;
  } while (wordDelimiters[(u_char)text[endWord]] || !text[endWord]);
  *pos = endWord;
  return 0;
}

/**
 * getWord        ищет позиции начала и конца слова в text
 * text           [in]     текст со словами
 * wordDelimiters [in]     множество разделителей слов
 * start          [in,out] позиция в text, начиная с которой ищем слово
 *                         при возврате это позиция начала слова или конца text
 * end            [out]    сюда заносим позицию первого разделителя после слова
 *                         или позицию конца text
 *
 *   возвращает 1, если слово найдено или 0 если слов больше нет
 */
int
getWord (char *text, char wordDelimiters[256], int *start, int *end)
{
  int i = *start;

  while (wordDelimiters[(u_char)text[i]])
    i++;
  *start = i;
  if (!text[i]) {
    *end = i;
    return 0;
  }
  while (text[i] && !wordDelimiters[(u_char)text[i]])
    i++;
  *end = i;
  return 1;
}

long long mutime(void);  // текущее время в микросекундах (realtime)

/*
 * ./a.out [desiredWordsNumber] вывод в stdout предложений из строки stdin,
 *         содержащих desiredWordsNumber слов.
 *         При вызове без аргументов выводит в stdout все предложения.
 *         Если строка текста начинается с ЧИСЛА, то предложения 
 *         в stdout не выводятся, а производится измерение времени исполнения
 *         ЧИСЛА циклов программы.
 *
 * основной алгоритм
 *         В цикле из введенного в строке текста выбираем очередное слово,
 *         считаем слова в предложении.
 *         Начало первого слова в предложении запоминаем, 
 *         в качестве начала предложения.
 *         После каждого слова проверяем наличие одного из символов конца
 *         предложения. Если предложение содержит desiredWordsNumber слов,
 *         то выводим его в stdout и сбрасываем счетчик слов в предложении.
 */
int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  char   *text = NULL, wordDelimiters[256], sentenceDelimiters[256];
  size_t textSize;
  int  wordStart, endWord, curpos, wordCnt,  sentenceBegin,
    desiredWordsNumber = av[1]? atoi(av[1]):0;

  makeset(wordDelimiters,delims);
  makeset(sentenceDelimiters,sdelims);

  // для замера времени
  FILE *out = stdout, *nullout = fopen("/dev/null","w");
  int  nloops, i;
  long long tstart;

  while (puts("Enter text"),getline(&text,&textSize,stdin) > 0) {

    // для замера времени
    if ((nloops = atoi(text)) < 1)
      nloops = 1;
    if (nloops > 1) {
      out = nullout;
      tstart = mutime();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < nloops; i++) {

      // собственно цикл подсчета слов в каждом предложениии и печать
      wordCnt = wordStart = 0;
      while (getWord(text,wordDelimiters,&wordStart,&endWord)) {
        if (!wordCnt)
          sentenceBegin = wordStart;
        wordCnt++;
        if (isSentence(text, wordDelimiters, 
                         sentenceDelimiters, endWord, &curpos)) {  
          if (desiredWordsNumber < 1 || wordCnt == desiredWordsNumber) {
            int i;
            for (i = sentenceBegin, fputc('[',out); i < endWord; i++)
              fputc(text[i],out); 
            fputs("]\n",out);
          }
          wordCnt = 0;
        }
        wordStart = curpos;
      }

    } // конец цикла замера времени
    if (out == nullout) {
      out = stdout;
      long long dt = mutime()-tstart;
      printf ("%d loops %lld%s\n", nloops,
          dt < 10000? :dt/1000, dt < 10000? " usec" : " msec");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

#include <sys/time.h>

long long
mutime()
{
  struct timeval t;

  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  long long mt = (long long)t.tv_sec * 1000000 + t.tv_usec;
  return mt;
}
```

Теперь результаты (время) трех вариантов.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ -O3 nwords.c -o nwords
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./nwords 
Enter text
1000000 и пишу я тесты. разные тесты. тесты, тесты, тесты... что толку от них?
1000000 loops 2222 msec
Enter text
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ -O3 tstrtok.c -o tstrtok
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./tstrtok 
Enter text
1000000 и пишу я тесты. разные тесты. тесты, тесты, тесты... что толку от них?
copytime 129 bytes 1000000 loops 21 msec
1000000 loops 1795 msec
Enter text
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ g++ -O3 ncwords.c -o ncwords
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./ncwords 
Enter text
1000000 и пишу я тесты. разные тесты. тесты, тесты, тесты... что толку от них?
1000000 loops 1211 msec
Enter text
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Интересно было бы сравнить с boost вариантом, предложенным [[[[@gkuznets](/users/5638/gkuznets)](/users/5638/gkuznets)](/users/5638/gkuznets)](/users/5638/gkuznets). Естественно, вариант не должен оставлять после себя модифицированный начальный текст.

Никто из любителей С++ не хочет? А то у меня что-то с бустом не заладилось.

Comment: Благодарю за труды

Comment: @RubyNub, из `man strtok` :

    char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr);

    ...

    The strtok_r() function is a reentrant version strtok().   The  saveptr argument  is  a pointer to a char * variable that is used internally by strtok_r() in order to maintain context between successive  calls  that parse the same string.

    ....

    Different strings may be parsed concurrently using sequences  of  calls to strtok_r() that specify different saveptr arguments.

Середину объяснения (из `man`) выбросил, т.к. не влезает в лимит длины комментария.

См. продолжение.

Comment: (продолжение)

Если кратко, то **strtok** работает так:

При первом вызове она находит первое слово, ограниченное разделителями, записывает в str после него 0, запоминает этот адрес **в своей внутренней static char \*** переменной и возвращает адрес начала слова.

При втором (и т.д.) вызове вместо str ей передается NULL, и для поиска следующего слова, она использует запомненный у себя адрес.

А в `strtok_r` вместо внутренней переменной мы подсовываем ей свою. Когда вызываем strtok_r и str NULL, то для поиска очередного слова берется адрес из saveptr. 

Почему передаем адрес saveptr понятно?

Comment: @avp, распиши пожалуйста trim, если тебе не трудно. А то вообще не понимаю ни принципа ни алгоритма его работы.

Comment: @RubyNub, trim возвращает копию предложения (в динамической памяти (или еще говорят "в куче")).

Сначала ищем первый символ *не разделитель*. Начиная с него делаем копию (вызываем strdup). Теперь от конца копии идем к началу, пока не встретится символ *не разделитель*. Вместо следующего за ним разделителя записываем 0 (т.е. конец строки). 



(комментарии закончились. буду продолжать в дополнениях ответа).

Comment: @avp, премного благодарен вам. Но все-таки забыл один момент у вас уточнить
while (puts("Enter text"),fgets(text,1024,stdin))
Вот это вот условие внутри оно вообще как интерпретируется? Или как оно звучит на словах? И запятая пугает еще)

Comment: @RubyNub, в Си,С++ всюду, где можно написать *выражение* можно написать *список выражений* (через запятую). Результатом выполнения списка  будет результат последнего выражения.

Соответственно, `(puts("Enter text"),fgets(text,1024,stdin)` означает: вызвать функцию `puts()` а затем функцию `fgets()` и `while` будет исполняться, пока результат `fgets` не равен нулю (т.е. пока не конец ввода).

Просто так компактно записывается "приглашение" с последующим вводом строки.

Answer (score 9):

Можно реализовать другим, более читаемым, способом. Только скорее всего это не то, что вам нужно (-;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/trim.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::algorithm;

int wordsNumber(const std::string& sentence) {
    auto wordsIterator = make_split_iterator(
            sentence, token_finder(is_any_of(" "), token_compress_on));
    return std::distance(wordsIterator, decltype(wordsIterator)());
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Enter sentences\n";
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    std::cout << "Enter desired words number\n";
    int desiredWordsNumber;
    std::cin >> desiredWordsNumber;

    std::vector<std::string> sentences;
    boost::split(sentences, input, is_any_of("!?."));
    for (const auto& sentence: sentences) {
        std::string trimmedSentence = trim_copy(sentence);
        if (wordsNumber(trimmedSentence) == desiredWordsNumber)
            std::cout << trimmedSentence << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот он -- C++. "Многабукофф" -- это более читаемо?

Comment: @gkuznets, а если boost не установлен?

И еще, конечно, код интуитивно понятен, но Вы уверены, что все тонкости вызова нестандартных функций очевидны без комментариев?

А вот для этого

     for (const auto& sentence: sentences) {

какой компилятор нужен?

Comment: Мой ответ не про boost, который может быть не установлен. Уверен, что тонкости вызова нестандартных функций неочевидны без чтения документации.

Comment: Я знаю только 2 компилятора, которые могут это собрать: gcc4.7 и clang. Остальные пока в пролете. 

@avp, а теперь попробуем написать то же самое на чистом С. И сколько "букофф" будет там?

Comment: +1, но вы чересчур формально подошли к понятию "предложение". А если оно заканчивается многоточием? Четырьмя восклицательными знаками, как любят многие мои одноклассники? Я бы в качестве улучшения эвристики требовал наличие пробела после точки и т. п. и заглавной буквы после него. Кавычки, скобки и прямая речь ещё более усложняют задачу.

Comment: @mikillskegg "чистый C" включает использование pcre? И задача исходная, или то, что получилось у @gkuznets?

Comment: И я думаю, не все согласятся, что функция `wordsNumber` читаемая. Хотя концептуально она хороша.

Comment: @mikillskegg, первый раз на чистом Си "букоффок" получится много, во второй раз их еще добавится (и уже в нескольких файлах), а вот третий и дальше будет примерно столько же, как в примере @gkuznets.

Comment: Мне кажется, общее количество букв не настолько существенно, главное, чтобы было поменьше новых сущностей. Пример: если у меня подключается `"mystringtools.h"`, и оттуда импортируется `size_t getWordCount(const std::string&)` или `size_t getWordCount(const char*)`, понимаемость кода ничуть не хуже вне зависимости от C++ или С-стиля. Сама функция может быть реализована по-разному, снова-таки, главное, чтобы понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите `strtok` из `string.h.`
Вот, например, как кол-во слов можно искать:

```
unsigned wordsCount( string str, string separators )
{
   char *word = new char[ str.size() + 1 ];
   strcpy( word, str.c_str() );

   unsigned count = 0;

   word = strtok( word, separators.c_str() );
   while( word ) {
      ++count;
      word = strtok( NULL, separators.c_str() );
   }

   delete [] word;

   return count;
}
```

Пример использования:

```
string inputStr = "We think in generalities, but we live in details.";

cout << wordsCount( inputStr, ", " );
```

Обратите внимание, что в вызове `strtok` первый параметр `char*` (**НЕ** `const char*`).

Comment: memory leak в wordsCount.

Comment: @gkuznets: ... и неоправданное копирование данных

Comment: @gkuznets, спасибо) забыл delete word;
а вот про копирование.. @VladD, где именно? параметры функции?

Comment: @LoOny, не "delete word;", a "delete [] word;". Иначе UB.

Comment: @dzhioev, ага. поправил. Очень давно не писал на с++, всё напрочь позабывал) Но сама задумка с использованием strtok нормальная или всеже пользоваться функциями из boost?

Comment: Код до сих пор содежит грубую ошибку в управлении памятью, так что рано говорить о преимуществах split_iterator перед strtok.

Comment: @LoOny: (раз уж @gkuznets не подсказывает) вы удаляете вовсе не тот указатель, который выделяли -- бида!

Comment: Но это не совсем беда, указатель то NULL, т.о. **ничего не удаляется**.

Comment: т.е. word нужно было сохранить, завести другую переменную для strtok,  затем удалять word? 
только в конце word наверно всётаки не NULL.. а указатель на первый символ последнего слова, нет?

Comment: @LoOnly, думаю вместо word для результата strtok() надо использовать другую переменную. Ее удалять не надо, strtok() сама подберет все внутреннее хозяйство, когда возвратит NULL. А вот после этого word надо удалить.

--

Вообще меня чем-то заинтересовала эта задачка. Попробую разные варианты и оценю время исполнения. Сейчас есть 3 шт., измерение времени еще не делал.

Для начала в моем ответе Ваш (с strtok()) вариант. Программа получилась компактная и по моему весьма понятная. Естественный недостаток - это копирование данных и "потеря"  разделителя предложений.